# InfoPath list box - How to change the validation message "Only numbers allowed"?

Tags: infopath, validation

This is SP2010, InfoPath 2010. I've got an InfoPath form. Form has a listbox which is bound to external data. The Value is a number, and the Display is a descriptive list for humans. I have, in the Drop-Down List Box Properties, changed the ScreenTip to "Please choose a Widget."

Problem is, on the published form, mousing over the listbox displays the message "Only numbers allowed", as a little popup in the upper-left of the textbox. My desired ScreenTip message displays in the lower-right.

How do I get rid of that confusing "Only numbers allowed" message? I've tried a Validation rule on the listbox, but this only alters the ScreenTip message which appears in the lower-right of the listbox.